# Possible to re-enable IPv6 without rebooting?

Tags: centos5, ipv6

I have a machine running CentOS 5.8.  IPv6 was disabled by creating a file `/etc/modprobe.d/disable-ipv6` with the following contents:

```
options ipv6 disable=1
```

Removing the file and rebooting the machine should re-enable IPv6.  Is there a way to enable IPv6 without having to reboot?

---

**Additional info:**

I found something that said to `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/interface/disable_ipv6`, but `/proc/sys/net/ipv6` does not exist on this machine.

`sysctl` shows nothing about IPv6:

```
# sysctl -a | grep -i ipv6 | wc -l
0
```

The ipv6 kernel module is loaded:

```
#lsmod | grep ipv6
ipv6                  437857  1 cnic
```

Attempting to remove it throws an error:

```
# modprobe -vnr ipv6
FATAL: Module ipv6 is in use.

# modprobe --show-depends ipv6
insmod /lib/modules/2.6.18-308.13.1.el5/kernel/crypto/crypto_api.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/2.6.18-308.13.1.el5/kernel/net/xfrm/xfrm_nalgo.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/2.6.18-308.13.1.el5/kernel/net/ipv6/ipv6.ko
```

Modprobe says `crypto_api` depends on the ipv6 module.  Unloading and loading that on a running webserver does not sound like best idea.

I tried `rmmod` as suggested by @Zoredache:

```
# rmmod -v ipv6
ERROR: Module ipv6 is in use by cnic
```

Comment: Try rmmod ipv6, and then try re-inserting it?

Comment: @Zoredache Tried it, same results as modprobe -r (module in use).  I could probably force it with -f, but at that point I'd rather just go the "clean" way and reboot the machine.

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to reload the ipv6 driver without a reboot

```
$ /sbin/lsmod |grep ipv
ipv6                  438625  3 rdma_cm,ib_addr,cnic

# loop through all the dependent modules, and unload them 
$ rmmod cnic ...
$ rmmod rdma_cm

$ modprobe ipv6 disable=0
```

You may need to turn off the n/w, but this should avoid the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible.  I ended up rebooting the machine to enable IPv6.  I'd love for someone to prove me wrong since I have a slew of other machines configured the same way.

Comment: For future readers: This is one of many reasons that we advise not disabling IPv6 even if you aren't yet deploying it.

Answer (score 0):

i've got it working,

before:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

do this :

```
$ modprobe ipv6
$ sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
```

after:

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

hope this helps